# Anyone flown Alaska Airlines that's a "passenger of size"?

Tags: air-travel, seating, alaska-airlines

I am heading to Hawaii soon with 2 friends.  I am looking at ticket prices for all of us.  I am leaning towards Alaska Airlines.   I am 330 pounds and am concerned about fitting into Alask Airlines seats. Has anyone my size ridden on Alaska Airlines?

Comment: The seats on Alaska are not meaningfully different than other airlines.  You can find specific dimensions here: https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Alaska_Airlines/information.php.  All airlines have a Passenger of Size program where you can reserve the adjacent seat for a discount.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Customers of size seating guidelines of Alaska Airlines](https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/policies/seating-customers-of-size.aspx) has all the information you need, here I have extracted the most critical parts of the aforementioned guidelines:

> We require the purchase of an additional seat for any customer who
>   cannot comfortably fit within one seat with the armrests in the down
>   position. The armrest is considered to be the definitive boundary
>   between seats; **width between the armrests typically measures 17 inches
>   for coach and 21 inches for First Class**. The purchase of an additional
>   seat(s) serves as a notification to Alaska Airlines of a special
>   seating need, and allows us to adequately plan for the number of seats
>   that will be occupied on the aircraft.
>
> After you have completed travel, if all Alaska Airlines flights in
>   each direction departed with an open seat available, you will be
>   eligible for a refund of the second seat.
>
> ### Refund instructions
>
> You can request a refund by using our [online form](https://www.alaskaair.com/feedback/general-comments) or contacting
>   Customer Care at 1-800-654-5669. Simply provide the name on the
>   ticket, travel dates, flight information and ticket number.
>
> ### Seatbelt extensions
>
> The seat width on all Alaska Airlines aircraft (armrest to armrest) is
>   approximately 17 inches and the **seatbelt length is approximately 46
>   inches.** Passengers needing extra coverage may ask the flight attendant
>   for **a seatbelt extension, which adds 25 inches to the seatbelt length**.
>   Only seatbelt extensions provided by the specific aircraft operator
>   may be used onboard.
>
> Seat belt extensions are prohibited:
>
> - in Exit Rows
> - Rows 1 and 6 on Alaska Airlines flights 1-999